# Question on Lévy processes and corresponding characteristic functions/Laplace exponents

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, laplace-transform, characteristic-functions, levy-processes

I'm new to the world of Lévy processes. I understand that all  Lévy processes $X = (X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ have the following property: For $t\geq 0$, there exists a characteristic function $\phi$ defined by $\mathbb{E}\Big[e^{i\theta X_t}\Big] = e^{-t\phi(\theta)},\quad\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

I'm currently reading a paper where the following Lévy process is used:

$$X_t = \bigg(r - \delta -  \frac{\sigma^2}{2} - \lambda \mathbb{E}[Z_1]\Bigg)t + \sigma W_t + \sum_{k=1}^{N_t}In(Z_k+ 1)$$

where $r$, $\delta$, $\sigma$ are constants. $N_t$ is a Poisson process, and $Z_k's$ are i.i.d randon variables. The paper then uses the following definition for the characteristic function (and Laplace exponent, saying they are equivalent):

$$\mathbb{E}\Big[e^{\theta X_t}\Big] = e^{t\phi(\theta)},\quad\theta \in \mathbb{R}.$$

What properties does $X$ possess so that this definition of characteristic function can be used?? I feel like I am missing something very obvious. Many thanks!

Comment: the characteristic function of a real random varibale always exists, as $e^{i\thetaX_t}$ is bounded (the absolute value is one) for all $\theta \in\mathbb{R}$. The laplace transform on the other hand need not exist. Hence the two things are not equivalent-not even in the case of Levy processes. However, you get the characteristic exponent if you insert $i\theta$ into the laplace exponent (for $\theta \in\mathbb{R}$). Could you post a link to the paper.

Comment: https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2543702 page 12, I believe. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The process you mentioned is a special Lévy process, the pure discontinuous part of this Lévy process is a compound Poisson process. May be the Chapter 2 of following book could provide related information about it: A. E. Kyprianou, *Fluctuations of Lévy Processes with Applications*, 2nd Ed., Springer,(2014).